# How to find $ \int \frac{x^8}{e^{2 x}+1} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help with this $$ \int \frac{x^8}{e^{2 x}+1} \, dx$$  Can't figure it out. 
I tried with partial integration, and I lose myself.

If someone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you really need the primitive and not just the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case $1$: $x\leq0$

Then $\int\dfrac{x^8}{e^{2x}+1}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^8e^{2nx}~dx$

$=\int\left(x^8+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nx^8e^{2nx}\right)dx$

$=\dfrac{x^9}{9}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^8\dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}8!2^{k-9}n^{k-9}x^ke^{2nx}}{k!}+C$

Case $2$: $x\geq0$

Then $\int\dfrac{x^8}{e^{2x}+1}~dx$

$=\int\dfrac{x^8e^{-2x}}{e^{-2x}+1}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^8e^{-2(n+1)x}~dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^8\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}8!2^{k-9}(n+1)^{k-9}x^ke^{-2(n+1)x}}{k!}+C$

Answer (score 6):

> *Can't figure it out.*

[No wonder you can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)), since it's [not expressible in terms of elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). We do, however, have the following two identities: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx~=~n!~\zeta(n+1)$$ and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx~=~n!~\eta(n+1),$$ see the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)  functions for more details.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-z}{\mathrm d}x=\Gamma(s)\frac{1}{z}\mathrm{Li}_s(z)$ with the [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).